# Vs code Python Interpreter Invalid Version Python error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I use remote-ssh extension to connect to remove linux server. From there I do development.

All of a sudden, I got this `Invalid Version Python` error when loading conda env. It had been working fine. I have reinstalled vs code and Python interpreter. This error still persists. Python Interpreter also disappeared from the menu bar at the bottom.
[image]

Version information:
[image]

Anyone know the root cause of this is? Thanks in advance.

Error Log:

```
Error 2021-04-09 10:43:13: Failed to parse version from path: /research/anaconda3/envs/poc_test_env/bin/python [Error: invalid version python
    at u (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:9:198256)
    at Object.c [as parseVersion] (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:9:197565)
    at p.buildPathEnvInfo (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:80:29369)
    at p.resolveEnv (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:80:29309)
    at E.resolveEnv (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:29:4121)
    at t.PythonEnvsReducer.resolveEnv (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:61:762313)
    at async t.PythonEnvsResolver.resolveEnv (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:61:763669)
    at async u.doResolveEnv (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:61:757654)
    at async q.getInterpreterDetails (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:80:38813)
    at async C.getInterpreterDetails (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:61:741545)
    at async f.updateDisplay (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:61:729765)
    at async f.refresh (/home/test/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.3.680753044/out/client/extension.js:61:729292)]
```

VS code version info:

```
Version: 1.55.0 (user setup)
Commit: c185983a683d14c396952dd432459097bc7f757f
Date: 2021-03-30T16:01:55.261Z
Electron: 11.3.0
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

Comment: It looks like this is a new known issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15856

Comment: @Kemp Thx. I just commented on the thread.